# Why does $n/\sqrt n = \sqrt n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I just graduated from uni in computer science, but decided I want to relearn calculus. I discovered that $\frac {n}{\sqrt n} = \sqrt n $ for every positive integer $n$. Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Try multiplying both sides by $\sqrt n$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could see it from different ways. For instance, since $$n = \sqrt{n}\cdot \sqrt{n}\tag{1}$$ (by definition of the square root, $x = (\sqrt{x})^2$ for all $x\geq 0$), you get
$$
\frac{n}{\sqrt{n}} = \frac{\sqrt{n}\cdot \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}}
= \sqrt{n}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}} = \sqrt{n}\cdot  1 = \sqrt{n} \tag{2}
$$
by dividing both left- and right-hand-side of the equality in (1) by $\sqrt{n}$.

---

*It is not only for integers, incidentally. This works for every positive real $x>0$.*

Answer (score 5):

It is because $(\sqrt n)^2=n$.

Answer (score 1):

One way to show two quantities are equal is to show that the square of their difference is zero, i.e. $(a-b)^2=0$ and in our case it is $$\Big( \frac{n}{\sqrt{n}}-\sqrt{n}\Big)^2=\frac{n^2}{n}+n -2\frac{n}{\sqrt{n}}\cdot \sqrt{n}=0$$